# why my custom command not showing in autocad console after loading my dll

Tags: autocad-plugin

i'm trying to create custom command for autocad but i have the following setup:
- i have visual studio 2013 and 2015 both installed in the same order
- i have autocad 2015 and 2018 both installed in the same order

i am new to this so correct me if i am wrong about the requirement for this
-in order to create custom dlls for acad 2015 we need vs 2013
-in order to create custom dlls for acad 2018 we need vs 2015

when i load dll created in vs 2013 in acad 2015 it works fine 
but the problem is when doing the same for acad 2018 
it show's nothing on acad console (meaning nothing happen in the loading process) but when i type my command nothing shows up

i am sure there is a way to check if a dll is successfully loaded from some log some where i just don't know what and where

if any one know what i am talking about please help
thank you

Comment: What language are you programming in?  If you're using C#, VB.net, etc. the version of Visual Studio doesn't matter (other than referencing the correct AutoCAD DLLs).  If you're programming in Object ARX then the version of Visual Studio matters.

Comment: i am using C# with the help of the dot net managed dlls provided by autodesk

Comment: with the help of the dot net wizard to create autocad pluging i am not sure if this is ObjectARX or not  but it ask about objectARX SDK location . sorry if i confused you as i mentioned earlier i am new to this and thank you for you replay

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to tell if something loaded correctly is to add an Editor.WriteMessage("Insert message here...") into the end of your Initialization function.

If the DLL loads correctly from a NETLOAD command or from your Bundle configuration, the message will be displayed on the command line.

Comment: it is working now every thing loading fine  thank you for you help